# Disable clustering in JGroups

Tags: infinispan, jgroups

I'm extending some tests for a system where Infinispan with JGroups is used for clustering. During the test execution, the application is mostly booted up and therefore JGroups is building a cluster. This leads to clustering of Jenkins builds in case of parallel builds, which produces side effects that fail the tests randomly.

Sadly I cannot change much of the configuration, however I can provide a new infinispan.xml and a new jgroups.xml file for test execution. I fiddled a lot with these config files trying to purposely ruin clustering by binding to random ports, disabling loopback etc., but JGroups is just too robust to fail.

I'm searching for a config which makes sure that a lookup of new nodes fails, even though the cluster name is the same for multiple parallel processes.

My configs look like this (I can change pretty much everything except the transport tag):

infinispan.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<infinispan xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="urn:infinispan:config:11.0 http://www.infinispan.org/schemas/infinispan-config-11.0.xsd"
        xmlns="urn:infinispan:config:11.0">

    <jgroups>
        <stack-file name="jgroups" path="jgroups-test.xml"/>
    </jgroups>
    <cache-container statistics="true" default-cache="local-cache" >
        <jmx enabled="true" />

        <!-- Sadly I cannot remove transport altogether since the application code always requires a cluster -->
        <transport cluster="mycluster"/>

        <local-cache-configuration name="__vertx.distributed.cache.configuration"/>

        <!-- a lot of local caches here which are distributed in the main infinispan.xml... -->
    </cache-container>

</infinispan>
```

jgroups-test.xml:

```
<config xmlns="urn:org:jgroups"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="urn:org:jgroups http://www.jgroups.org/schema/jgroups-4.2.xsd">

    <UDP bind_addr="match-address"
        bind_port="0"
        receive_on_all_interfaces="false"
        receive_interfaces="255.255.255.255"
        disable_loopback="true"
        enable_diagnostics="false"/>

    <TCP bind_addr="match-address"
        bind_port="0"
        enable_diagnostics="false"
        client_bind_port="0"
        receive_on_all_interfaces="false"/>
</config>
```

Any help on this curious matter is highly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're missing the `stack` attribute on your `transport` element, so you're still using the `udp` stack bundled with Infinispan.

```
        <transport cluster="mycluster" stack="jgroups"/>
```

However, you have by now removed enough protocols from the stack that I don't think it's usable as is.

The best option to avoid interfering with existing clusters is to use only `TCP` or `TCP_NIO2` as a transport (no `UDP`) and `LOCAL_PING` as the discovery protocol (no `PING` or `MPING`).

For reference, this is what the Infinispan test suite uses:

https://github.com/infinispan/infinispan/blob/main/core/src/test/resources/stacks/tcp.xml

You can make `UDP` work as well if you set a different `mcast_addr` for each cluster and/or you disable `ip_mcast`, but it's much easier to go with `TCP` and `LOCAL_PING`.

Comment: You are a genius, works perfectly. I just threw away my jgroups.xml altogether and configured everything in infinispan.xml:

`<jgroups>
    <stack name="mytcp">
        <TCP .../>
        <LOCAL_PING/>
        <pbcast.NAKACK2 .../>
        <pbcast.STABLE .../>
        <pbcast.GMS .../>
    </stack>
</jgroups>

<cache-container statistics="true" default-cache="local-cache">
    <transport cluster="cluster-cirrus" stack="mytcp"/>
    ...`